# both, one or another (12|1|2) regex anywhere search using the same name on subpatterns

Tags: python, regex

I achieved the search (12|1|2) with the following regex:

```
^(?:(?=.*?(?P<one>1))(?=.*?(?P<two>2))|(?=.*?(?P<otherone>1))|(?=.*?(?P<othertwo>2)))
```

And it matches any line if finds 1 and 2, 1 or 2. Like all those following scenarios:

```
1anything anything2

1 anything

anything 2
```

The problem is that I don't want to call the other groups `otherone` and `othertwo`. I wan't to call it `one` and `two` but I can't because subpatterns can't have the same name.

I heard about `Branch Reset Group` but it do not work on native python regex and I'm using a pretty big repo to migrate from `re` to `regex`. Is there any alternative to achieve that?

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/s5d9e0/1

Comment: `12|1|2` looks like an awkward way to write `1?2?`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica the problem is that I can't match an empty string so it must have both or one of them

Comment: Ah, right, forgot about that.

Comment: Without the PyPi regex module, there is no other plain regex alternative.